# Which css element to target to change the look of this button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to change the look of the button on my wordpress site but I can figure out which element to target in order to change it. I tried targeting: `.input#chained-quiz-action-1` but the button remains unchanged.

Comment: I don't see any "Go ahead" button

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @abney317 Hi, apologies, it was only for logged in users. You should be able to see it now.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a period in front of `input` would be if you had a class named input. Remove the period

`.input#chained-quiz-action-1`

should be

`input#chained-quiz-action-1`